# Get 404 error when try to get the assets CSS in codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, codeigniter

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Here is the htaccess file (but i doubt is it the root cause)

When I try to access the css file , it show 404 (Not Found)  (The codeigniter  404 page, not the server 404) , so I suspect it is setting problem , but in fact , all the css and js in includes/header.php can import, the only problem is those fonts file(I am using bootstrap)

So, all font files like `assets/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff` shows 404, how to fix it? sorry for my bad english, thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you give us your view file ? (HTML)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Are you sure you include your files correctly ?
Example:

```
<?php echo base_url('/assets/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff');?>
```

Have you check the permissions of your woff file ?